# Update a value and set a local variable in a case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

I am trying to update a value in the database but also want to set a local variable `VAR_IS_RATE_LIMITED`. The reason for this is because I do not want to use a select statement and want to execute it within one. How can I set the `VAR_IS_RATE_LIMITED`? I looked at other questions but their CASE statements weren't embedded in an update statement.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION F_RATE_LIMITED(P_IP varchar(45),
                               P_MAX_RATE int unsigned
                            )
RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
BEGIN

    DECLARE VAR_IS_RATE_LIMITED INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    INSERT INTO rate_limit (ip, rate)
        VALUES (P_IP, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        rate = 
            CASE
                WHEN (rate + 1) > P_MAX_RATE THEN
                    SET VAR_IS_RATE_LIMITED = 1;
                    rate
                ELSE
                    rate + 1
            END;

    RETURN VAR_IS_RATE_LIMITED;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do that, it does not work that way, you can't set a variable in an `update` statement.

Comment: @Stu Is there a solution to what I am trying to do without using a select statement? Essentially what I want is that if you have exceeded the rate, I want the function to return 1.

Answer (score 0):

To set something during a data modification statement, it has to be part of an expression, not a statement.  And as far as I know you can't set a stored function variable in an expression.  But you can set a user variable:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION F_RATE_LIMITED(P_IP varchar(45),
                               P_MAX_RATE int unsigned
                            )
RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
BEGIN

    SET @VAR_IS_RATE_LIMITED = 0;
    INSERT INTO rate_limit (ip, rate)
        VALUES (P_IP, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        rate =
            CASE
                WHEN (rate + 1) > P_MAX_RATE THEN
                    CASE WHEN @VAR_IS_RATE_LIMITED := 1 THEN rate END
                ELSE
                    rate + 1
            END;

    RETURN @VAR_IS_RATE_LIMITED;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Here the variable is set in a CASE test (you can also use an IF expression) that is always true so rate is always returned from the CASE.

Comment: in theory you could just check FOUND_ROWS() after the INSERT; it should be 1 if a row was inserted, 2 if a row was updated, and 0 if the limit was hit so no change happened.  But I couldn't get it to work.